# Format letters into text (similar to how you might have date (D-M-Y) = 10 January 2015)

Tags: python, formatting

This is a relatively simple script (basically it's a dictionary containing information on how to edit the input text), but I'm trying to learn to write stuff properly. The commented bit at the top seems a bit messy, but I'm not quite sure how else to demonstrate all the functions in action.

Function names are also not my strong point, and I had to choose `.add()` to temporarily add things (as in `x+a` instead of `x = x+a`), as it seemed to fit with `x2 = x1.add(stuff)`.

`.replace()` is to add new values or replace existing ones (basically the dictionary update function), and `.update()` adds new values, or appends to a list if the key already exists.

In terms of the variable names, I know mixed case isn't used much anymore, but as I've learned in Maya where all the functions are mixed case, I kinda use it without thinking and it'd be hard to switch over. I did the underscore method for the comments so it'd possibly be easier to understand.

```
import random
class TextFormat:
    """
    Format text to replace letters with values. A random value will be chosen if a list has been input.
    For adding or removing values, it behaves like a dictionary.

    Functions:
        TextFormat().update()
          -  Add new rules, or add new items to existing rules
        TextFormat().replace()
          -  Add new rules, and replace any existing ones
        TextFormat().add()
          -  Temporarily add new rules to assign to a new variable
    Operatons:
        Add (+)
          -  TextFormat()+dict
          -  It will combine with a dictionary using TextFormat().update() function and output a new TextFormat object.

    Create class object
    >>> animal_format = TextFormat( a=["cat", "dog"], A="lizard" )

    #TextFormat( a=["cat", "dog"], A="lizard" )

    Convert text using the rules
    >>> animal_format( "I like /as but I really want my own /A." )
    'I like dogs but I really want my own lizard.'

    Add a new rule temporarily for the current text
    >>> animal_format( "I have a /a but I'd quite like a bird, maybe /b.", b=["a falcon", "an eagle"] )
    "I have a cat but I'd quite like a bird, maybe an eagle."

    #TextFormat( a=["cat", "dog"], A="lizard" )

    Add a new rule permenantly and replace any existing rules
    >>> animal_format.replace( b=["a falcon", "an eagle"], a="hamster" )

    #TextFormat( a="hamster", A="lizard", b=["a falcon", "an eagle"] )

    Add a new rule permenantly, or update an existing rule with a new item
    >>> animal_format.update( b=["a falcon", "an eagle"], a="guinea pig" )

    #TextFormat( a=["hamster", "guinea pig"], A="lizard", b=["a falcon", "an eagle"] )

    Remove a rule (three ways)

    >>> animal_format.pop('a')              # These two will cause an error if any key doesn't exist
    ['hamster', 'guinea pig']
    >>> del animal_format['b']              # .pop() will return the item, whereas del won't

    >>> animal_format.remove( 'b', 'A' )    # This will not cause an error if any key doesn't exist

    #TextFormat( a=["hamster", "guinea pig"] )


    Other example with names:

    >>> titles_male = ["Mr","Dr","Rev","Lord","Sir","Officer"]
    >>> format_titles = TextFormat( t=titles_male )

    Build list of names
    >>> name_list = [("Robert Jason Smith"),("John Michael Mellor")]

    Repeat for however many names there are
    >>> name = "Robert Jason Smith"
    >>> split_name = name.split()
    >>> name_first = split_name[0]
    >>> name_middle = split_name[1]
    >>> name_last = split_name[2]

    Create new TextFormat object
    >>> format_name = format_titles.add(F=name_first, f=name_first[:1], M=name_middle, m=name_middle[:1], S=name_last, s=name_last[:1])

    >>> print format_name("/F /m. /S")
    Robert J. Smith

    >>> print format_name("/t /f. /S")
    Mr R. Smith
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __repr__(self):
        return "TextFormat({p})".format(p=', '.join(k+'='+str(v) for k,v in self.kwargs.iteritems()))

    def __call__(self, input, **kwargs):
        """Format the input text."""

        tempKwargs = self.kwargs.copy()
        tempKwargs.update(kwargs)

        for replacement in tempKwargs:

            #End up with a single word from the selection
            if isinstance(tempKwargs[replacement], (list, tuple)):
                newWord = random.choice(tempKwargs[replacement])
            else:
                newWord = tempKwargs[replacement]

            #Replace any markers in the input with the word
            input = input.replace('/'+replacement, str(newWord))

        return input


    def update(self, keepValues=True, **kwargs):
        """Add new rules or update existing ones."""

        originalKwargs = self.kwargs.copy()
        for addition in kwargs:

            oldValue = originalKwargs.get(addition, None)
            newValue = kwargs[addition]

            #Get value already in kwargs
            if not isinstance(oldValue, (list, tuple)):
                if oldValue is not None:
                    oldValue = [oldValue]
                else:
                    oldValue = []

            if oldValue != []:

                #Update new value
                if not isinstance(newValue, (list, tuple)):
                    newValue = [newValue]
                else:
                    newValue = list(newValue)

                #Update original value
                for value in newValue:
                    #Check it doesn't already exist
                    if value not in originalKwargs[addition]:
                        try:
                            originalKwargs[addition] = oldValue+newValue
                        except Exception as e:
                            originalKwargs[addition] = oldValue+tuple(newValue)

            else:
                originalKwargs[addition] = newValue

        #Keep values by default, but don't keep if you have a+b
        if keepValues:
            self.kwargs = originalKwargs
        else:
            return TextFormat(**originalKwargs)

    def replace(self, **kwargs):
        """Add new rules or replace existing ones."""
        self.kwargs.update(kwargs)

    def remove(self, *args):
        """Remove rules by letter."""
        for letter in args:
            try:
                del self.kwargs[letter]
            except Exception as e:
                pass

    def add(self, **kwargs):
        """Temporarily update the dictionary with new values."""
        return self+kwargs
    def __add__(self, other):
        """Add a dictionary - (a+b)"""
        return self.update(False, **other)
    def __radd__(self, other):
        """Add a dictionary - (b+a)"""
        return self.update(False, **other)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """Get item from dictionary."""
        return self.kwargs[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """Set dictionary item."""
        self.kwargs[key] = value
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        """Delete item from dictionary."""
        del self.kwargs[key]
    def pop(self, key):
        """Pop item from dictionary."""
        return self.kwargs.pop(key)
```

I've also just learned about doing things like `__add__` and `__call__` and so on to override things in classes, so I've been trying to find opportunities to use them.

Comment: Python's built-in string formatting already has some of this, for example: `"I like {a}s but I really want my own {b}.".format(a='dog', b='lizard')`

Comment: Oh damn haha, that hadn't crossed my mind, well my code no longer seems useful ;p    And oops, I'll quickly go through and fix them, I'd changed various bits of code after writing them so just changed the syntax and hoped for the best

Comment: I kinda followed the bits I know from it, though not with the comments at the start of the code, I'd seen someone else do it in a similar format so copied that

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, fixed now :)    Also, I'm wondering if the `__repr__` part is done correctly, or if there's a better way of having it work with `**self.kwargs`?

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware of the `doctest` module, but yeah I'm getting a few errors. Most are due to how I showed the example (eg. `.replace()` doesn't return anything so I showed the current state of the class), or due to the code randomly selecting another value. One is because I show different ways to delete the same keys. I'm not quite about the unexpected indent though, if you remove the `>>>` bits it all works fine. For the record however, sorry for not mentioning, I'm on python 2.7, so print won't work quite the same.

Comment: If I should be writing comments so it literally shows the output and not the state of the class (which will still cause the errors with random values but oh well), how would you suggest to show the state when nothing is returned?

Comment: Would `object` be useful in the class definition? I've never come across anything that explains the use of it haha. And is it ok to leave it as proper examples which may not relate to the output (as in showing the state of the class), or is the general idea to only show the output and let people figure out what's going on in the class from the comments?

Comment: Yes, it would; it makes it a "new-style" class (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/3001761). And yes, there's no problem leaving examples in comments, but you should add a clear note that they **aren't** doctests to avoid confusion like mine! Alternatively, make them doctests - this is useful for you, too, as it lets you easily check whether it's still working as you develop it (*"regression testing"*).

Comment: Ah thanks for the link, that's useful to know. I've just about managed to get it working as a doctest, but the random elements make about 2 errors each time. And that's a really good point about them, I'd never thought of it like that, I just presumed it was always excessive documentation aha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python already includes quite a few string formatting options, e.g. `'%s, %s!' % ('hello', 'world')` and `'{}, {}!'.format('hello', 'world')` For anything other than learning purposes, I'd suggest using these rather than reinventing the wheel - they handle a lot of edge cases you may not have considered!

---

**Docstrings**

Good work including them, it gives a lot of examples of how the class should be used. However, when I first saw them, I assumed they would run with [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html); unfortunately, most of them don't! It wouldn't take much effort to make them work; the crucial part is using [`random.seed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed) to make sure the randomised cases come up the same every time. You then have combined testing and examples built right into your code.

Rather than bundle so many cases into a single docstring, I would spread the appropriate tests out across the methods, and then just have a single *"bringing it all together"* example in the overall class docstring. I wouldn't bother documenting the trivial one-liner magic methods that just expose `self.kwargs`, unless they were doing something unexpected.

---

**Style**

Python has [a style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which should generally be followed. In particular:

- Watch whitespace around parentheses (e.g. `animal_format( "I like /as but I really want my own /A." )` should be `animal_format("I like /as but I really want my own /A.")`;
- Be consistent with spacing between methods in the class (a single blank line); and
- Variable names should be `lowercase_with_underscores`.

---

**`__repr__`**

As you asked about it specifically, I would be tempted to implement `__repr__` by basically cheating:

```
'TextFormat(**{!r})'.format(self.kwargs)
```

Rather than `'TextFormat(a='a')'` you get `'TextFormat(**{'a': 'a'})`, but it still does what you need it to!

---

**Classes**

You should avoid *"old-style"* classes in new code; this means that you should always inherit from `object`. However, as you're implementing what is basically a dictionary, I would instead use [`collections.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMapping), which is designed for exactly this sort of thing (note that in the code below I have similarly used `collections.Sequence` in `TextFormatter._prepare_dict` rather than `(list, tuple)`, allowing it to correctly handle all sequence arguments). You have to implement the `__len__` and `__iter__` magic methods on top of `__***item__`, but these again pass through to `self.kwargs` without any fuss. This makes it work everywhere you'd expect a dictionary to work.

---

**Other functionality**

A few other notes:

- Rather than special-casing single strings, note that `random.choice` from a list with only one item always returns the same thing. This significantly simplifies the logic in `__call__`.
- I would factor out the `'/'` indicating a character to be replaced, for example to a *class attribute*. This makes it easier to change later if you want to.
- If you need both keys and values from a dictionary, iterate over `dict.items`.

---

In all, then, here's what I would have done:

```
from collections import MutableMapping, Sequence
import random


class TextFormatter(MutableMapping):
    """Text formatter to replace letters with values.

    A random value will be chosen if a list has been input. For adding
    or removing values, it behaves like a dictionary.

        >>> random.seed(0)
        >>> animal_format = TextFormatter(
        ...     a=['cat', 'dog'],
        ...     A=['lizard', 'snake', 'turtle'],
        ... )
        >>> animal_format('I like /as but I really want my own /A.')
        'I like dogs but I really want my own turtle.'

    """

    REPL_TEMP = '/{}'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._prepare_dict(kwargs)
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __repr__(self):
        """Create a representation of the instance.

            >>> fmt = TextFormatter(a='a')
            >>> fmt
            TextFormatter(**{'a': ['a']})

        """
        return 'TextFormatter(**{!r})'.format(self.kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def _prepare_dict(dct):
        """Make sure all values are lists.

        All sequences are converted to lists, placing strings as single
        elements in lists:

            >>> dct = dict(a='a', b=['b'], c=('c',))
            >>> TextFormatter._prepare_dict(dct)
            >>> dct == dict(a=['a'], b=['b'], c=['c'])
            True

        Non-sequences are rejected out of hand:

            >>> dct = {'a': set(('b'),)}
            >>> TextFormatter._prepare_dict(dct)  # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
            Traceback (most recent call last):
            TypeError: ...

        """
        for key, val in dct.items():
            if isinstance(val, basestring):
                dct[key] = [val]
            elif not isinstance(val, Sequence):
                raise TypeError('Arguments must be sequences.')
            dct[key] = list(val)

    def __call__(self, text):
        """Carry out the specified replacements.

        If only one choice, just use it:

            >>> fmt = TextFormatter(a='b')
            >>> txt = TextFormatter.REPL_TEMP.format('a')
            >>> fmt('test {}'.format(txt))
            'test b'

        If multiple choices, pick one randomly:

            >>> random.seed(0)
            >>> fmt = TextFormatter(a=list('abcdefg'))
            >>> txt = TextFormatter.REPL_TEMP.format('a')
            >>> fmt('test {}'.format(txt))
            'test f'

        """
        for key, val in self.kwargs.items():
            repl = random.choice(val)
            text = text.replace(self.REPL_TEMP.format(key), repl)
        return text

    def remove(self, *keys):
        """Remove the specified keys from the mapping.

            >>> fmt = TextFormatter(a='a', b='b', c='c')
            >>> fmt.remove(*'ac')
            >>> fmt.kwargs == {'b': ['b']}
            True

        Non-existent keys are just ignored:

            >>> fmt.remove('d')
            >>> fmt.kwargs == {'b': ['b']}
            True

        """
        for key in keys:
            if key in self.kwargs:
                del self.kwargs[key]

    def update(self, keep_values=True, **kwargs):
        """Add new replacement rules or update existing ones.

        New keys are simply added in:

            >>> fmt = TextFormatter(a='a')
            >>> fmt.update(b='b')
            >>> fmt.kwargs == dict(a=['a'], b=['b'])
            True

        For existing keys, with 'keep_values' (the default), new values
        are added:

            >>> fmt = TextFormatter(a='a')
            >>> fmt.update(a='b')
            >>> fmt.kwargs == dict(a=['a', 'b'])
            True

        Without 'keep_values', new values replace old ones:

            >>> fmt = TextFormatter(a='a')
            >>> fmt.update(False, a='b')
            >>> fmt.kwargs == dict(a=['b'])
            True

        """
        self._prepare_dict(kwargs)
        for key, new_val in kwargs.items():
            if key in self.kwargs and keep_values:
                self.kwargs[key].extend(new_val)
            else:
                self.kwargs[key] = new_val

    def __add__(self, other):
        """Create a new formatter from two mappings.

        Works with two formatters:

            >>> fmt = TextFormatter(a='a') + TextFormatter(b='b')
            >>> fmt.kwargs == {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['b']}
            True

        or a formatter and dict in either order:

            >>> fmt = {'a': 'a'} + TextFormatter(b='b')
            >>> fmt.kwargs == {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['b']}
            True

        """
        fmt = self.__class__(**self.kwargs)
        fmt.update(**other)
        return fmt

    __radd__ = __add__

    # This stuff all just exposes self.kwargs, dict-style

    def pop(self, key):
        return self.kwargs.pop(key)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.kwargs[key]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.kwargs[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.kwargs)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.kwargs[key] = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

The logic behind dealing with `kwargs` in `__call__` didn't quite follow for me, so I've left that out, but you can easily implement this following my example. For example, should:

```
fmt(txt, ...)
```

be equivalent to something like:

```
fmt.update(...)
fmt(txt)
fmt.undo_update()  # back to what it was before, somehow
```

If so, why doesn't it accept `keep_values`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, it was helpful reading through, and yeah it kinda was for learning purposes. And as to the kwargs in `__call__`, they are also added temporarily, but it's supposed to be an alternative solution to make it easy to use (and a one line way). I did get a bit sloppy with spaces around brackets with the doctest, I'm not usually that bad, but underscores is a little harder to switch to since Maya entirely uses the mixed case, and half my things are for Maya (I'll try though). The `__repr__` idea is good, but the result doesn't look as nice as the other way aha

Comment: I didn't quite understand the `collections.MutableMapping` part though, is the main difference with `object` being that if you don't override anything like `__add__` in the class, it'll behave just like a dictionary would or something, whereas with `object` it may not work in all cases? I didn't notice anything out of the ordinary using an old style class, so what exactly would be the difference? ;p

Comment: @Peter try switching to `(object)` (new-style class, but not a mapping) or `()` (old-style class), *rerun the tests* and see what happens. That's the whole point of having automated testing; you can immediately see what changes mean.

Comment: With the code I wrote it doesn't seem to make any difference haha, with yours it causes two more errors, but you have also written some bits in a way I probably wouldn't ;p    (eg. I've never seen `self.__class__(**self.kwargs)` before, I presume it's similar to `self.kwargs.copy()`)

Comment: No, it isn't - it *unpacks* the dictionary as keyword arguments to `__init__` again - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters.

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry I didn't think about the `self.__class__` part, I found before that `globals()[self.__class__.__name__]()` is the same as calling the class again, but without having to type the name, is your way basically very similar to this, but not so ugly?  Anyway, I get what `MutableMapping` does now that `object` doesn't haha, thanks again :)

Comment: How did you find `globals()[self.__class__.__name__]()` before `self.__class__()`?!

Comment: Haha, well I found `self.__class__.__name__()` returned the name of the class (didn't cross my mind that `self.__class__` was the actual class), but it wouldn't do anything as it was text, so I googled around a bit and found you could treat text as a class by getting the matching class from globals :)